# Can we set a size to variable in PHP? if yes then how?

Tags: php

in lang we set a size like this `int a[10];`
so
Like "C" lang. can we set a size to a variale in PHP?

Comment: No. In PHP, arrays automatically shrink and expand as needed.

Comment: Hey, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: Valid question, so why all the downvotes - downvoters might actually discover something they never knew themselves from @georg's answer

Answer (score 1):

PHP built-in arrays are essentially hash tables, not sequential chunks of memory like in C. Therefore, the term "size" doesn't actually apply here. The hashtable-based implementation is flexible (you can grow and shrink the array anytime), but not particularly efficient, so php developers added another array type, [`SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php), that works in a way similar to C arrays: you allocate an array, providing its size, and this size remains the same during the lifetime of the program. This makes array operations much faster (according to the comments on php.net, up to 30%).

Comment: Note that you can adjust the size of an SPLFixedArray after it has been created, but it's not recommended as it's an expensive operation in terms of execution time